# How to run beans one after another

Tags: javabeans

I have created a project in which it has to run beans while initiated. 
I have created 3 beans in dispatcherServlet.
How to run those beans in a order like there are 3 beans like A,B,C
it should run one after another. First A then B and then C

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a framework like Spring and assuming that by "running the beans" you mean something like an `ApplicationRunner` which runs once during the start up of the application you can simply annotate the bean methods with `@Order`.
The higher the number, the later the runner starts.

If instead the beans are dependencies you should inject them into each other in the necessary order (A into B and B into C). Then the framework will resolve them in the order needed.